# How to view Jenkins pipeline stages in order in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that sends the stages status to the Gitlab merge request.

The stages are ordered alphabetically in Gitlab. How can I view them based on there order in Jenkins (not alphabetically).